# (Jquery/Javascript) Event Handle - Lose Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, focus

here's my question, i'm developing a personal website that has a huge animation in the background, with clouds moving around in an infinite loop.
Everything is done with jquery extended with jquery timers and sprites.
|
First it fills out the cloud starting position matrix (random)
|
it set's the actual position of each cloud.
|
start moving the clouds with .animate() function and start a timer to fire again that animation until the clouds reach the left border.
|
repeat forever :)

Anyway this method consume a "little" memory and CPU, i'm trying to optimize the code,
and i was wondering **if there's a method to call a function when the browser switch to a different page**, to stop the animation.

Thanks.

Plus, if anyone would help in optimizing code, i will appreciate so much! :) 
I'll post the link to the website if anyone could help with that.
Thanks Again

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you animate a **single** DOM-element, not a bunch of individual clouds. Put your clouds into a container and move the latter.

Second, take a look at [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions). They are *much* smoother (GPU-accelerated), than JavaScript-based animation. Also, super-easy to learn and use. Just describe a CSS class and add it to your clouds upon initial position setting.

As for the determining if the browser tab is in the background, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame),   <s>used by jQuery as animation ticker</s> which is a 60 FPS ticker, can do that for you *automatically*.

---

It appears, jQuery is no longer using `requestAnimationFrame` (they [used to](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/298) at some point, but then removed it). So, here's [an animate function](https://gist.github.com/1376200) employing `requestAnimationFrame` (with a `setTimeout` shim for IE) you can steal ideas from (or just grab the function itself).

Answer (score 2):

You could listen to the window's `blur` and `focus` events:

```
$(window).on('blur', function() {
    // window went into background, stop animations here
    // ...
});

$(window).on('focus', function() {
    // window became active, start animations here
    // ...
});
```